# I want some logic in this query using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a two tables first one is called `teams` and second one is called `cpd` and I want this result required (*see result screen below*). I tried myself but was not successful (*see practice query below*).

> teams table

```
id    name               sub_cat_id
1     SACRAMENTO KINGS   19
2     KINGS              19
3     MIMAMI HEAT        19
4     HEAT               20
5     KITE               20
```

> cpd table

```
id team_id status added_date
1  3       1      2012-05-26
2  3       1      2012-05-27
3  3       0      2012-05-28
```

> practice Query

```
SELECT 
t.`id`,t.`name`,IFNULL(cpd.status,0) AS resultStatus,IFNULL(cpd.added_date,CURDATE()) AS added_date
FROM `teams` t
LEFT JOIN cpd  ON cpd.team_id = t.id 
WHERE t.`sub_cat_id` = 19 OR cpd.added_date = CURDATE()
```

> Result Screen (Required only those rows are black color in screen)

[image]

Update

> Explanation ?

1. I am trying to get those rows who they are related with `sub_cat_id = 19` like this in team table
2. Join `team table` with `cpd table` for `cpd.status filed`
3. `cpd.status` must be related with current date  in `cpd table` like `2012-05-28`

Comment: `t.`sub_cat_id` = 19` **AND** `cpd.added_date = CURDATE()`

Comment: When i execute this query like this they return me only one record @forsvarir

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do?  The results could be achieved with `select id, name, 0, CURDATE() from teams where sub_cat_id = 19`

Comment: @forsvarir see my update on my answer

Comment: Given what you've described, why are you expecting more than one row?  You should just be getting 'MIMAMI HEAT', because it's the only team that has a row in the CPD table.  Is that not right?  What do you want if there isn't a row in the CPD table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one way to get the desired result:

For example:

```
SELECT t.`id`,t.`name`,
       IFNULL(cpd.status,0) AS resultStatus,
       IFNULL(cpd.added_date,CURDATE()) AS added_date
FROM `teams` t
INNER JOIN cpd  ON (cpd.team_id = t.id AND cpd.status = 0) 
WHERE t.`sub_cat_id` = 19 
      OR 
      cpd.added_date = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanx for replying me ......... or you must have to change this `cpd.resultStatus = 0` into this `cpd.status = 0` either your logic is perfect

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
t.`id`,t.`name`,IFNULL(cpd.status,0) AS resultStatus,IFNULL(cpd.added_date,CURDATE()) AS added_date
FROM `teams` t
LEFT JOIN cpd  ON cpd.team_id = t.id 
WHERE t.`sub_cat_id` = 19 OR cpd.added_date = CURDATE()
GROUP BY t.id

Comment: If you edit your answer, highlight it and click on the {} button, it'll format it as code instead of the current output.

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN `ON cpd.team_id = t.id`only matches one tuple with the cpd table so for the other tuples date is set as NULL (because you are doing  LEFT JOIN) and hence the where query gives only one tuple